# Не округляется border

Tags: html, css

Задал градиент `border`, и свойство `border-radius` перестало работать

```css
input {
  width: 235px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin-top: 35px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(1deg, #b5b748, #6ac248);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

input.background-form__input_2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input class="background-form__input_1" type="name">
  <input class="background-form__input_2" type="telephone">
</form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в px тоже пробовал, не помогло

Comment: [border-radius нельзя использовать с border-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706963)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант так себе, но вполне рабочий

```css
label{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:1px;
  background:linear-gradient(1deg, #b5b748, #6ac248);
  margin-top:35px;
  border-radius:20px;
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
input {
  display:block;
  width: 235px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius:inherit;
  border:none;
  margin:0;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label><input class="background-form__input_1" type="name"></label>
  <label><input class="background-form__input_2" type="telephone"></label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот более менее правильный код:

```css
.rounded-corners-gradient-borders {
  border: double 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at top left, #b5b748,#6ac248);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input class="rounded-corners-gradient-borders" type="name">
  <input class="rounded-corners-gradient-borders" type="telephone">
</form>
```

Comment: padding-left не работает, отступы внутри текста закрашиваются